# How to Data model for an educational application in FirebaseFirestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to implement a student-Teacher Interaction application where students can learn any number of courses  from teachers in that particular field. I have a data model that stores all the short objects of students who are enrolled to a  course under a teacher which will be stored under Teacher main object and  all the the short objects of teachers who teach that student under Students main object. My question is how do I update changes to all the short objects of this Teacher,if he updates his profile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is related to where your background is for example if you are coming from relational database there then you need to reference ids etc.. then think the same way too does not hurt something to know is that you can use the same thinking in firestore too.

Comment: I still did not get what will be the right way to model the db then

Comment: Think as if you do not need joins etc.. as every firestore query is shallow that means that you can access child without accessing its parent hope it help in case you need my help please do ask.

Comment: I may not need joins,but how will I get a list of students who are being taught by teachers without using, multiple queries